# How do I disable the d: namespace in Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

For reference, I am using Blend 4...

I have been experiencing a lot of headaches with the auto-generation of the `xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"` namespace, and the associated "d:LayoutOverrides", etc. I do not want this code, and have to remove it all the time because the other developers I work with do not want it in the code. Is there a way to disable Blend from generating this code? I understand that it is there to help the design process but it is not necessary for me and the benefits are not outweighing the code cleanup costs. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it really is causing problems (my thoughts are that these 'other' developers are not being particularly pragmatic), then just start using VisualStudio to write your XAML.

If the you're using Blend because you're going to be more productive due to having a highly styled UI to build, then these other developers need to see that the benefits by far out weigh the negatives of having the odd little bits of markup that get added (which in turn will make your life easier).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response James. This is a highly styled UI but the thing is that I really don't see any benefit from from the auto-generated code in the d: namespace. I can just deal with it if I absolutely have to, but was just wondering if anyone knew of a modification or work around in Blend that will turn this off.

Comment: @Matt - It's pretty much so that you can save design time specific information. Things like saving when layers are visible or invisible, design time view models, etc.  As xaml files are just text files (which is hugely beneficial when using version control, as opposed to flash's binary .fla files which are a nightmare to version control) Blend can't save this information in any other way.

Comment: it also allows you to have sizes defined only for design purposes and ignored at runtime (I love this). i.e: you design a control whose size is entirely base on the content, that will be provided at runtime. Without the mc:Ignorable="d", you cannot see anything when you design in blend since the control's size is 0. the mc:Ignorable="d" allows you to specify d:Width=100 and d:Height=50 for instance, so that you can actually see what you are doing without messing the dynamic nature of the result.

Comment: @David, I understand all of these benefits, but I have ways of working around these and do not necessarily need any of the d: code at all. I see how many people like it, but I don't need it.

Comment: @James - Well I do, most of what I do is visual UI stuff that looks rather butchered in Visual Studio's designer. I take advantage of the majority of Blend's benefits, just not these few trivial things that's all. I'm sorry if I wasted anyone's time and I guess I will just deal with it.

Comment: @Matt - I think the point we're trying to make is that you're not doing anything wrong apart from being pushed into removing this markup because other developers are asking you to do so.  There's nothing wrong with it being there, it doesn't do any harm and it's ignorance that causing you to remove it.

Comment: I agree with James on this one. As far as I know, you're stuck with blend's behaviour (the options are very limited in blend, and I don't know about one that deals with your issue). So your only hope is that the other devs will finally see the light. But I'm afraid they won't, as long as they haven't used blend at least a little.